# Raspberry Camera turns off everytime I pull the plug to restart

Tags: raspbian, pi-3b+, camera, power, raspbian-buster

I'm using [ivport-v2](https://github.com/ivmech/ivport-v2) and followed the guide to get my camera running. Went in sudo raspi-config enabled I2C and Camera, then reboot and everything works fine. However, when I pull the plug on my RPi it causes those settings to restore to default (off).

This is an issue for me as I would like my RPi to run without me needing to login everytime and re-enable the camera. How can I permanently enable my settings?

Some extra details if needed:

- Specs: Raspberry Pi 3 Model B
- OS: Version 10.11 Buster

Comment: Has your sd card failed and gone read only? You should be doing a shutdown not pulling the plug!

Comment: Well wrote a few services and those get saved just fine and run when I launch my RPi so I don't think thats it. I agree that I should be doing a shutdown but I'm trying to put this RPi in a production environment where the only way it will be turned on and off is in that manner since no one is going to be logging into it

Comment: In fact it even remembers that I should have SSH turned on. But for some reason Camera keeps turning off

Comment: Update: turns out the camera was on all along. It's just ivport's code which does not recognize the camera for some reason? https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=1947799#p1947799